# Load/Display page of last searched value

Tags: javascript, html

Problem: submit form  with "window.onload" create looping infinity.(form submitting non-stop)

When user visit page, I use the saved value to do searching once the page load, with

```
    window.onload = function() {    

if (localStorage.getItem("datePicked")){
        document.getElementById("searchPickDate").value = localStorage.getItem("datePicked");
    }

    document.getElementById("searchDateForm").submit();
}
```

searchDateForm form:

```
<form id='searchDateForm' name='searchDateForm' action='' method='POST'>
<input type='date' id='searchPickDate' name='searchPickDate' > 
<input type='submit' value='Search' onclick="return searchDatebtn();" >
</form>
```

this is the code to save the search value:

```
function searchDatebtn() {
    var asdf = document.getElementById("searchPickDate").value;
   localStorage.setItem("datePicked", asdf);
   return true;
}
```

I tried so many ways and digging the internet so hard but still failed to ***stop the looping***. Any idea? 
Thank you

Comment: It will loop because after the page loads, the form will submit, which refreshes the page, and when it loads again...well, you know what will happen. Why exactly would you submit the form right after the page loads? The form does not even have any values yet

Comment: try using ajax to load the search item

Comment: _“Any idea? ”_ - same idea as always: Start by properly describing to us what you want to _achieve_ here (instead of only showing us which wrong path you are on already.)

Comment: @CarlBinalla i edited post..  the form has its value when page onload.

Comment: @nickzoum this is what I want to find out

Answer (score 1):

Submit will send you to the url you have set in  the form  action="" attribute
in your case the attribuie is empty, so the browser assumes it is your current url and it will take you to that url

Submit is kind of bad for user experience
In your case you should retrieve your last picked date
and use it to fetch last searches from server with an ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Instead of submit your form call directly your function.

```
window.onload = function() {    
    searchDatebtn();
}
```

And if you don't want to refresh the page, return false in your search function

```
function searchDatebtn() {
    var asdf = document.getElementById("searchPickDate").value;
   localStorage.setItem("datePicked", asdf);
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the date is already stored in the `localStorage` to stop the infinite loop :

```
window.onload = function() {    
    if( localStorage.getItem("datePicked") != null ){  
        document.getElementById("searchDateForm").submit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
window.onload = function() {    
var searchKey = localStorage.getItem('key');
  if(searchKey != ''){
    document.getElementById("searchDateForm").submit();
    localStorage.setItem('key', '')
  }
}
```